# updating 2 fields in mysql (with one update being null update)

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm basically trying to do this:

```
update <table> set process_flg='N' where id<1201;
update <table> set time_stamp=null where id<1201;
```

this works fine if I use 2 different updates.
but, if I compress them to be:

```
update <table> set process_flg='N' and time_stamp=null where id<1201;
```

it just doesn't work.

the **time_stamp** remains the value it was while **process_flg** becomes 0.

Comment: use `,` (comma) instead of `and` when you are updating multiple fields

Comment: Please upvote and mark the answer correct if it resolves your problem.

Comment: yes, that is working.
but, what happens when 'and' is used?
it seems then only the first field gets updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see your your compressed query and there is mistake. Your compressed query should be like below:

> **UPDATE  SET process_flg='N', time_stamp=null WHERE id<1201;**

You need to use "**,**" instead of "and" statement.

Please take a look here more information:
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp